# How to display var from javascript to html?

Tags: html

I keep getting an error for the last line in generatePassword(),"            document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = outHash;" Any ideas on how to display this variable?

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Enter your text here </p>
    <input type="text" value="Enter password here" id="userInput">
    <button onclick="generatePassword()">Generate</button>
    
    <p>Hash output <span id="output"></span></p>
    
    <script>
        function generatePassword() {
            var Input = document.getElementById("userInput");
            var outHash = digestMessage(Input);
            var displayHash = [];
            document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = outHash;
        }
        async function digestMessage(message) {
            var encoder = new TextEncoder();
            var data = encoder.encode(message);
            var hash = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
            return hash;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You are getting this error because you are trying to add **innerHTHML**, when what you are looking for **textContent**. Use, `document.getElementById("output").textContent = outHash`.

Comment: Typo: You need to pass the **string** `"output"` to `getElementById`, not the `output` *variable* that you are passing.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen — No. That's a syntax error. (innerHTML is fine since SHA-256 won't generate strings with HTML special characters in them, but `<div>outHash</div>` isn't valid JS)

Comment: @Quentin yep, you are right, my bad. I read your comment and yes you are very right!

Comment: And as @Quentin pointed out, you have to use _string_ for id when using `getElementById()`.

Answer (score -1):

Change `output` in `document.getElementById(output)` to a string (`"output"`) and it should work. Your javascript is trying to call a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: `Input` is not a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, it is. You can tell by the orange coloring.
It's not because of the capitalization of the word; it's because it's a reserved word.

Comment: Demo: https://jsbin.com/xurabuzuse/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Actual list of reserved words: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_keywords_as_of_ecmascript_2015 (none of which start with a capital letter).

Comment: Alr, I'll edit my answer I guess.

Comment: Once you remove all the incorrect information in your answer, all that is left is pointing out the typo. This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: By "typo", do you mean how in their code it says `output` instead of `"output"`? Because that's already in my answer.